# Change navbar color depending on scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to alternate the navbar color depending on the scrollbar position at the moment, for example, if the scrollbar is on top of the page i would like the color to be transparent else, i would like it red.

This is my current code, at the moment what this is doing is that once the user scrolls a little bit, the navbar changes the color to red, but when the user goes all the way to the top again, that background color persists.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.listenScroll);
    }

    listenScroll = () => {
        if(document.body.scrollTop) {
            this.setState({ changeColor: "transparent" });
        } else {
            this.setState({ changeColor: "red" });
        }
    }
```

In other words, when the user scrolbar is on top, change color of the navbar to transparent, else, change it to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the scrolling element from the `event` that get's passed into your `listenScroll` function.

```
listenScroll = (event) => {
  if(event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop) {
    this.setState({ changeColor: "transparent" });
  } else {
    this.setState({ changeColor: "red" });
  }
}
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/dotspencer/mf93wexn/11/

Comment: Turns out to work listening to window as well. Updated my answer.